# How can I move my image to the left hand side of the page?

Tags: html, css, rotatetransform

```
This is my HTLM sample code
```

[image]

[image]

I have tried reading mdn documents and google however I am new and still don't understand how to fix this

Comment: Please include code as text, not images. We can't copy and paste code from an image. Better still provide a [mcve], which  includes the relevant CSS

Answer (score -1):

Use the align attribute in the img tag

```html
<img align="left|right|middle|top|bottom">
```

Hope it helps

Comment: The align attribute has been [deprecated for some time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/align) and should not be used